# Prevent nudging adjacent fontawesome/bootstrap icon on hover in table cell

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, icons, alignment, font-awesome

I made a fiddle to demonstrate my problem and what I'm trying to do.

http://jsfiddle.net/kvseelbach/rXEEZ/20/

I have tried the following CSS:

```
td a[class^="icon-"]:before, td a[class*="icon-"]:before { padding-right:2px; }
```

I am using FontAwesome with bootstrap and want to prevent the nudging of the second icon in each cell (display/edit record links) when the first link is hovered and enlarges. I tried border transparent, padding-right on :before item, etc. and haven't been able to perfect it.

How can I get this to work smoothly with CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest:

```
.dr-fxwidth {
    width: 48px;
    white-space: nowrap; /* <<< */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/rXEEZ/21/

It still tweaks the layout of the table, but doesn't cause the icon elements to trigger text-wrap.

Comment: Hmm, in case you didn't understand my question or your browser is rendering the table differently, here's an image. See how the icon beside the hovered link icon is pushed to the right a bit.

[Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/jQkFGwE.png)

Comment: Your fiddle completely wrapped the right icon under the left hovering the left icon. You're using `font-size: 110%;` to "grow" them, which is not particularly easy to deal with.

Comment: I noticed the icon was overlapping the original position of the adjacent, so I added some extra padding, but still have the same problem. See [Revision2](http://i.imgur.com/X7bOyfC.png)

Comment: Do you want the icon to grow in size when hovering?

Comment: If I set the "grow" size specified in pixels instead of percent, how could I prevent the nudge with CSS?

Comment: Hmm, I can't actually see the icon size increase on hover, but it looks cleaner this way. I like the spacing of the icons. Thanks.

Comment: It's all in the spacing on the `padding` on `:hover`: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/rXEEZ/30/